# How do i update my React or Material-ui to match package.json?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, material-ui, npm-start

I just upgraded my computer, and had to do an empty windows update, including installing react and material-ui back on my projects, along visual code etc. Now, the problem is that if I try to install material-ui or react (project level) I get an error, along the lines like this? The react in project is old, but with fresh install mine is the newer version.

````
C:\Users\eetu-\mylly_react>npm install @material-ui/core --save
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: mylly_react@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0" from @material-ui/core@4.11.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\eetu-\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\eetu-\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-02T23_21_20_429Z-debug.log```

I can manage new projects, but can't fix this.. Any advice? Thank you in advance!
````

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: This did not unfortunately help, as the same error pops up :(